# Child form opens in a new window

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

My child form opens up in a new window instead of opening within the MDI form when I use the below code:

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
f1.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;

this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

f1.Show();
```

Comment: Could you try `f1.MdiParent = this;` instead of `f1.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;`? I am not familiar with MDI but after a brief look it seems you're setting the new form's parent to the current form's parent rather than the current form itself.

Comment: f1.MdiParent = xxx where xxx is the mdi parent form, usually the main form of an mdi application

Comment: also do not set the dock property and do not set the windowstate property. These will be done by the mdi application automatic

Answer (score 2):

As @Keyur PATEL in comment suggested, you should set parent of "f1" form to the form object(not object MdiParent property) in which you want to inject "f1" form as MDI Child form ( not to the property of parent form, but to the object itself).

See more on [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications) about MDI Apps.

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;//This is not necessary,can work without it
f1.MdiParent = this; //try like this

this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

f1.Show();
```

Comment: f1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill is not necessary

Comment: @BhubanShrestha yes, but it is his code, I just edited what was wrong. :)

Comment: Nothing. But you could have mentioned that too.

Comment: it is also common to not set the windowstate in mdi applications, because each new mdi child form will be given the same WindowState as the other mdi child forms automatic